# Stop Citrix Workspace from starting when opening Citrix Viewer

Tags: macos, applications

I use Citrix Viewer to access one of my employer's applications.

Recently, when I open the `.ica` file from Safari to initiate the connection, in addition to Citrix Viewer, Citrix Workspace starts and pops up a really annoying, and really useless window.

[image: Image of the Citrix Workspace window]

[image: Image of Activity Monitor]

I'm on MacOS 12.6.3 in case that is relevant.

##### How can I stop Citrix Workspace from Starting?